# Issue centering image

Tags: html, css

We have a 2000px wide by 580px height image, currently this fits the screen i.e the arrow in the middle is centered when we re size the browser the image seems to loose its centering, I have seen this done whereby you have one large image centered and when the browser is re sized the image remains centered.

Can someone show me how this is done?

[image]

```
<div style="height:580px; margin-left:-10%; position:relative; max-width: 2000px; background-image:url("/content/largeImage.png")">
     <div class="container">
        <p>
          Do something else
        </p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 2000px means to fix. change into, such as, 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the cases you have seen, they most likely used a background image, which can be centered using `background-position`:

```css
header{
background:url('http://lorempixel.com/1500/500/') no-repeat;
background-position:center;
width:100%;
height:300px;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/8L2L1ey1/

Answer (score 0):

The following is a good approach to centre vertically and horizontally.

http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/03/centering-div-vertically-and-horizontally/demo.html

Comment: Please add the important pieces of that link here. That way, your answer will still be valid if the link target vanishes one day.